# Concatenate filename inside of CSV file for each line for multiple CSV files

Tags: shell-script, csv

I have lots of CSV files and I need the filename of each specific CSV file in every line of each file.

Original file content of `abc123.csv`:

```
ColVal_1;ColVal_2;ColVal_3
ColVal_4;ColVal_5;ColVal_6
```

New file content:

```
ColVal_1;ColVal_3;ColVal_3;abc123.csv
ColVal_4;ColVal_5;ColVal_6;abc123.csv
```

All CSV files are in the same directory. I don't want to specify the name of each file.

Answer (score 5):

Its much more simple, easier and faster with `sed` and `xargs`. Here `sed` uses in-place editing thus avoiding additional shell tools.

```
$ ls file{1..5}.txt|xargs -I% sed -i 's/$/;%/' %
```

And here is the output.

```
$ cat file{1..5}.txt
ColVal_1;ColVal_2;ColVal_3;file1.txt
ColVal_4;ColVal_5;ColVal_6;file1.txt
ColVal_1;ColVal_2;ColVal_3;file2.txt
ColVal_4;ColVal_5;ColVal_6;file2.txt
ColVal_1;ColVal_2;ColVal_3;file3.txt
ColVal_4;ColVal_5;ColVal_6;file3.txt
ColVal_1;ColVal_2;ColVal_3;file4.txt
ColVal_4;ColVal_5;ColVal_6;file4.txt
ColVal_1;ColVal_2;ColVal_3;file5.txt
ColVal_4;ColVal_5;ColVal_6;file5.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` you can do something like,

```
for f in *.csv
do
 sed -i 's/$/ '"$f"'/' "$f"
done
```

**Testing**

Inside one of the directories, I created couple of `csv` files.

```
cat csv1.csv

this
is
first
csv
file

##Second CSV file

cat csv2.csv

this
is
second
csv
file
```

Now, I executed the above command that I had mentioned. After the execution of the command, the files look like below.

```
cat csv1.csv

this csv1.csv
is csv1.csv
first csv1.csv
csv csv1.csv
file csv1.csv

##Second CSV file

cat csv2.csv

this csv2.csv
is csv2.csv
second csv2.csv
csv csv2.csv
file csv2.csv
```

If you want **semicolons** you can just add it in the `sed` command before appending the file name. Change the `sed` command like below.

```
 sed -i 's/$/ '";$f"'/' "$f"
```

**References**

http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/150545-merge-files-add-file-name-end-each-line.html

Comment: @Gnouc, Thanks for the edit. However, without double quotes it worked fine in my machine. :)

Comment: We need double quotes with file name contains special characters.

Comment: @Gnouc, ok that makes sense. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:-

```
for i in *.csv; do awk '{print $0 ";" FILENAME }' $i > ${i}.tmp ; mv ${i}.tmp ${i} ; done
```

You could avoid the `mv` if you have a later version of `awk` but this is probably more portable.

Comment: That's almost the solution, but this statements appends a line break and the filename for each line.

Comment: That's peculiar - it doesn't add a line break on my system! I get:-

`ColVal_1;ColVal_2;ColVal3;abc123.csv`

`ColVal`_4;ColVal_5;ColVal6;abc123.csv`

As two seperate lines (I can't get that to display here!)

Comment: I've ran this on both an Ubuntu 14.04 and a Fedora 20 system and both produce the correct result. What system are you running?

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -i.bak -ple '$_ .= ";"$ARGV' file.csv 
ColVal_1;ColVal_2;ColVal_3;file.csv
ColVal_4;ColVal_5;ColVal_6;file.csv
```

From `perldoc -v '$ARGV'`:

```
$ARGV   Contains the name of the current file when reading from "<>".
```

You can use `*.csv` to process all files in current directory. `-i.bak` option edit all files inplace and create backup files with name `*.csv.bak`.