# How can I combine different csv files from differenet folders with the name of each file as a column name in the combined file?

Tags: csv

I have a bunch of directories in which there are 3 .csv files with different names. For example, in my directories aa bb cc dd there are 3 files in each:

```
aa:  EA_sing_aa.csv    EA_ska_aa.csv   EA_tat_aa.csv
bb:  EA_sing_bb.csv    EA_ska_bb.csv   EA_tat_bb.csv
cc:  EA_sing_cc.csv    EA_ska_cc.csv   EA_tat_cc.csv
dd:  EA_sing_dd.csv    EA_ska_dd.csv   EA_tat_dd.csv
```

I want to add the name of each file to a new column as row names to each files and then combine all EA_sing*.csv files together and combine all EA_ska*.csv files together and also combine all EA_tat*.csv files together!
my out put will be just 3 files:

```
1) EA_sing.csv  ##the first column for the rows from EA_sing_aa.csv file
                will be aa and for the rows from EA_sing_bb.csv will be bb
                and for the rows from EA_sing_cc.csv will be cc..... ##   
2) EA_ska.csv
3) EA-tat.csv
```

How can I do this in *nix?
Thanks

Comment: Slow down and ask one clear question then build off that.  The way it's asked, it's unnecessarily difficult to parse and unlikely to be of use to others.

Comment: I don't understand this question. I'm really trying.

Comment: Basically, he has a lot of directories each with 3 CSVs with 3 name formats. He wants to iterate through the directories, consolidate all the similarly named files - with the file (or directory name?) as the leading column.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your input files and an example of your desired output files. How are the columns defined? Commas? Spaces? Tabs?

Answer (score 0):

This is an off the cuff answer:

```
for dir in $(ls ); do echo " $dir - this is the directory"; for csv in $(ls $dir/*csv); do cat $csv|sed -e "s/\(.*\)/$dir, \1/g"; done;  done
```

You could then add options to specify file names, e.g.

```
for myfile in EA_sing EA_ska EA-tat; do for csv in $(ls $dir/$myfile*)...
```

and then pipe them to a file of your choice, e.g.

```
do cat $csv|sed -e "s/\(.*\)/$dir, \1/g" >> $(echo "$myfile_complete.csv")
```

which might then be combined into something like this:

```
for dir in aa bb cc dd; do for file in EA_sing EA_ska EA_tat; do for myfile in $(ls $dir/$file*);do echo "parsing $myfile"; cat $myfile | sed -e "s/\(.*\)/$dir,\1/g" >> $(echo "$file\_combined.csv"); done; done; done
```

Or more to the point:

```
for dir in $(ls -d */); do for file in $(ls $dir*csv); do echo "this is my file $file"; cat $file|sed -e "s|\(.*\)|$(echo $dir|sed -e 's/\///g'), \1|g";done; done
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26256/discussion-on-answer-by-donnied-how-can-i-combine-different-csv-files-from-diffe).

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider using `find` - another very useful approach - e.g. look at:

```
find . -name "*csv" -exec grep "" {} + | sed -e 's/:/,/g' -e 's/\.\///g'
```

This is very similar to the questions described here:
[Concatenate filename inside of CSV file for each line for multiple CSV files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139148/concatenate-filename-inside-of-csv-file-for-each-line-for-multiple-csv-files)?

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554698/display-content-of-all-files-with-their-filenames-with-cat

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917413/cat-multiple-files-but-include-filename-as-headers

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864316/how-to-pipe-list-of-files-returned-by-find-command-to-cat-to-view-all-the-files

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the filename always being correct

```
for t in $(find . -iname "*.csv" | awk -F_ '{print $2}' | sort | uniq); do 
    awk -v OFS="," 'split(FILENAME,f,/[_.]/){print $0,f[4]}' $(find . -iname "*$t*.csv" | sort) > EA_$t.csv
done
```